# Testing correctnes of rewritten server from php to java

Tags: java, php, https, server, fork

I am pretty new to https so if say something inaccurate I am sorry.
I have running php server that was rewritten in java and now I need to test if it was rewritten correctly. I need to write a test that will listen to all post request on php, runs it on java server and compares java and php responses. Ideally saves responses on disc and compares files.

Problem is there seems to be very little on this topic and after intensive googling I have found technologies that could maybe help me. HtmlUnit dropWizard or software product line. Problem is I have no experience with any of them and from overview they are all time consuming just to set up.

Web server is https with client autorization and I am using mySQL database

Do you have any experenice with any of these technologies or any advice how should I tackle this problem?  Any tips or pointers would be most welcome.

Comment: Do you know the all the test cases you need to run?

Comment: I think this question is a little too broad for this forum.

Comment: Almost any integration test tool, like CodeCeption, will allow you to build up a test suite that can be run against both the PHP and Java apps